# Iterating over Dictionary(not iterable) and merging dictionaries, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

First of all I am very new to programming and this is my first question regarding programming. 
I am currently trying to automate simulations in greenius. I need to create a lot of scenarios that then will replace other parameters.

A dictionary of all my scenarios should look like this:

```
{'S1': 'a1, b1', 'S2': 'a1, b2', 'S3': 'a2, b1', 'S4': 'a2,b2', 'S5': 'a3,b1', 'S6': 'a3, b2'}
```

But if I try the following code I don't get the result I want.

```
def callback7():
  ax = int(SZ1) 
  bx = int(SZ2)
  for x in range(ax):
     Label(top, text='a'+str(x+1), relief=SUNKEN, width=5).grid(row=x, column=0)
     a.append(Entry(top, width=25))
     a[x].grid(row=x, column=1)
  for y in range(bx):
    Label(top, text='b'+str(y+1), relief=SUNKEN, width=5).grid(row=y, column=2)
    b.append(Entry(top, width=25))
    b[y].grid(row=y, column=3)
  B1 = Button(top, text='Save', width = 5,command=callback8).grid(row=0,column=4)

def callback8():
  for entry in a:
    Pa = entry.get()
    dcta['a{0}'.format(i)] = Pa
    i = i+1
  for entry1 in b:
    Pb = entry1.get()
    dctb['b{0}'.format(j)] = Pb
    j = j+1
  for key1, value1 in dcta.items:
    for key2, value2 in dctb.items:
        ar = value1
        br = value2
        dctz['S{0}'.format(u)] =  ar+'\t'+br
        u = u+1
```

The Error I am getting here is:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should **call** the method: it is `for key1, value1 in dcta.items()`, etc. not `for key1, value1 in dcta.items`.

Comment: oh my god and I tried to figure out what I was missing for hours... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

Change the alignment of your code . Alignment is wrong .It should be like below.

```
def callback7():
    ax = int(SZ1) 
    bx = int(SZ2)
    for x in range(ax):
        Label(top, text='a'+str(x+1), relief=SUNKEN, width=5).grid(row=x, column=0)
        a.append(Entry(top, width=25))
        a[x].grid(row=x, column=1)
    for y in range(bx):
        Label(top, text='b'+str(y+1), relief=SUNKEN, width=5).grid(row=y, column=2)
        b.append(Entry(top, width=25))
        b[y].grid(row=y, column=3)
    B1 = Button(top, text='Save', width = 5,command=callback8).grid(row=0,column=4)

def callback8():

    for entry in a:
        Pa = entry.get()
        dcta['a{0}'.format(i)] = Pa
        i = i+1
    for entry1 in b:
        Pb = entry1.get()
        dctb['b{0}'.format(j)] = Pb
        j = j+1
    for key1, value1 in dcta.items:
        for key2, value2 in dctb.items:
            ar = value1
            br = value2
            dctz['S{0}'.format(u)] =  ar+'\t'+br
            u = u+1
```

Comment: No that is not the Problem. I pasted it wrong into the Forum.